# get value out of really nested json array on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

how do I get values out of deeply nested json array.
I need to get all pairs of (nameValue and value) from below json

```
  var json = [{
                name: 'Firstgroup',
                elements: [{
                    name: 'Field1',
                    elements: [{
                        name: 'country32',
                        elements: [{
                            nameValue: 'city1',
                            value: 2025
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                    {
                        name: 'Field2',
                        elements: [{
                            name: 'country22',
                            elements: [{
                                nameValue: 'city2',
                                value: 1875
                            }]
                        },
                            {
                                name: 'country12',
                                elements: [{
                                    nameValue: 'city3',
                                    value: 1810
                                }]
                            }]
                    }]
            },
                {
                    name: 'Secondgroup',
                    elements: [{
                        name: 'Field1',
                        elements: [{
                            name: 'country52',
                            elements: [{
                                nameValue: 'city4',
                                value: 1310
                            },
                                {
                                    nameValue: 'city5',
                                    value: 1125
                                }]
                        }]
                    },
                        {
                            name: 'Field3',
                            elements: [{
                                name: 'country42',
                                elements: [{
                                    nameValue: 'city6',
                                    value: 1100
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                }];
```

I managed to get the first pair by this below piece of code

```
 function getDataProvider(array)
    {
        var dataPoint = [];
        var elements = 'elements';
        var name = 'nameValue';
        var value = 'value';

        var i, j, len;

       for (j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
           i = array[j];
           if (i[elements]) {
               this.getDataProvider(i[elements]);
            } else {
               dataPoint.push({
                   name: i[name],
                   value: i[value]
               });
            }
        }
       return dataPoint;
    }
```

how do i get all pairs out of the above json given that this json is dynamic which the depth of it is not known but it will contain pairs of (namevalue and value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a recursive function, calling itself when it has more elements and adding the values to its result whenever it comes across a result.

```js
var getNameAndValues = function(arr) {
  var nameValuePairs = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    if (item.value && item.nameValue) {
      nameValuePairs.push(item);
    }
    if (item.elements) {
      nameValuePairs = nameValuePairs.concat(getNameAndValues(item.elements));
    }
  }
  return nameValuePairs;
};

var json = [{
                name: 'Firstgroup',
                elements: [{
                    name: 'Field1',
                    elements: [{
                        name: 'country32',
                        elements: [{
                            nameValue: 'city1',
                            value: 2025
                        }]
                    }]
                },
                    {
                        name: 'Field2',
                        elements: [{
                            name: 'country22',
                            elements: [{
                                nameValue: 'city2',
                                value: 1875
                            }]
                        },
                            {
                                name: 'country12',
                                elements: [{
                                    nameValue: 'city3',
                                    value: 1810
                                }]
                            }]
                    }]
            },
                {
                    name: 'Secondgroup',
                    elements: [{
                        name: 'Field1',
                        elements: [{
                            name: 'country52',
                            elements: [{
                                nameValue: 'city4',
                                value: 1310
                            },
                                {
                                    nameValue: 'city5',
                                    value: 1125
                                }]
                        }]
                    },
                        {
                            name: 'Field3',
                            elements: [{
                                name: 'country42',
                                elements: [{
                                    nameValue: 'city6',
                                    value: 1100
                                }]
                            }]
                        }]
                }];

var result = getNameAndValues(json);
var asString = "";
for (var i = 0, len = result.length; i < len; i++) {
  var item = result[i];
  asString += item.nameValue + ": " + item.value + "<br/>";
}
document.body.innerHTML = asString;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for getting the wanted properties in an array.

```js
function getKeyValue(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(o) {
        if (o.elements) {
            o.elements.forEach(iter);
            return;
        }
        result.push({ name: o.nameValue, value: o.value });
    });
    return result;
}

var data = [{ name: 'Firstgroup', elements: [{ name: 'Field1', elements: [{ name: 'country32', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city1', value: 2025 }] }] }, { name: 'Field2', elements: [{ name: 'country22', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city2', value: 1875 }] }, { name: 'country12', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city3', value: 1810 }] }] }] }, { name: 'Secondgroup', elements: [{ name: 'Field1', elements: [{ name: 'country52', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city4', value: 1310 }, { nameValue: 'city5', value: 1125 }] }] }, { name: 'Field3', elements: [{ name: 'country42', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city6', value: 1100 }] }] }] }],
    result = getKeyValue(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A version which returns an array for every recursive call.

```js
function getKeyValue(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(
        o.elements
            ? getKeyValue(o.elements)
            : { name: o.nameValue, value: o.value }
    ), []);
}

var data = [{ name: 'Firstgroup', elements: [{ name: 'Field1', elements: [{ name: 'country32', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city1', value: 2025 }] }] }, { name: 'Field2', elements: [{ name: 'country22', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city2', value: 1875 }] }, { name: 'country12', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city3', value: 1810 }] }] }] }, { name: 'Secondgroup', elements: [{ name: 'Field1', elements: [{ name: 'country52', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city4', value: 1310 }, { nameValue: 'city5', value: 1125 }] }] }, { name: 'Field3', elements: [{ name: 'country42', elements: [{ nameValue: 'city6', value: 1100 }] }] }] }],
    result = getKeyValue(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```